# Monitor user's activity - login and logout

Tags: einstein-analytics, event, analytics, user-management, event-monitoring

I am trying to understand how can we know our user's activity each day on Salesforce. The aim is to know how much time each user spend in Salesforce each day, where the triggers are login at morning, and logout at evening. We have the event monitoring app and the event log files - so the data exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EventLogFile](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_elf.htm) object, Please read the doc, It supports SOAP and REST API.

Once you receive the data, check the value of `EventType` It should contain log files as per the document.

Another Doc [EventLogFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm), which is supported SOQL, please go through with this, this ma help.

Comment: Doesn't help with the "logout" concept... I wonder if there is any record of a "logout" event (I suspect not)

Comment: @PhilW, Yeah you are right, LoginHistory object does not give logout detail, I update the answer as I found some document about EventLogFile as a part of a release 15